# XCode / IOS process still running on iPhone after killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm working on a project that uses location services and I've noticed something strange on my test device (iphone 5).

If I quit the app (either using the stop button on xcode or double tap home and swipe up) I see that the location services arrow (next to the battery) is still on and filled in.

When I go into settings, privacy, location services, I see the arrow next to my app (set to Always) marked as purple and filled in - so it is definitely caused by me.

In my controller I have the following event listener

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

and this code

```
- (void)onAppWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.outdoorLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.outdoorLocation stopMonitoringForRegion];
}
```

The code definitely runs when I quit (I can see this if I add an NSLog line).

Rebooting the phone doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here are NSLog output of

```
NSLog(@"outdoor before stopping is %@", self.outdoorLocation);
// issue stop
NSLog(@"outdoor after stopping is %@", self.outdoorLocation);
```

produces

```
[194:5798] outdoor before stopping is <CLLocationManager: 0x1456ccb0>
[194:5798] outdoor after stopping is <CLLocationManager: 0x1456ccb0>
```

Comment: Check the value of `outDoorLocation` on `onAppwillTerminate:`. Is it nil?

Comment: Updated answer with NSLog info